# Subtraction with arrays

Tags: java, arrays, math, subtraction

Very simple question: I need the steps not the result please.

Background: I am taking very large numbers and storing them in an array. Then I either add or subtract the two. As it is an array I have to do it column by column. I have the addition done. But for the life of me cannot figure out/remember what to when subtracting a larger number from a smaller.

What are the steps in solving this question column by column?

```
   50
 -500
 -----
```

EDIT: They are stored in a int[]. Using arrays because it is the assignment requirement.
Just need to understand the logic of subtraction column by column.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using `BigInteger`?

Comment: storing them as WHAT in an array? string? .jpg image you need to OCR?

Comment: In this case, flipping the order and turning it into addition might be easier, making it -500 + 50

Comment: How do you represent negative numbers now?

Comment: @MarcB they are stored in an int[] as single digits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it that you are representing numbers as arrays of digits. So, for instance, 50 is represented by [5, 0] (or, perhaps more conveniently, [0, 5]). I also assume that you have some way of representing negative numbers (which you will need for subtraction).

You have a couple of options for dealing with subtracting a larger number from a smaller one:

- reverse the order of subtraction and then negate the result
- negate the subtractend and add the two numbers to obtain the result

The latter option assumes that your addition algorithm works for mixed-sign arguments and also works regardless of the magnitude of the minuend and subtractend. Both options assume that you have an algorithm for negating a number.

If you have no means of representing negative numbers, then the only thing you can do is signal failure when asked to compute 50 - 500 (since you have no way of representing the result).

Answer (score 0):

Going by following Assumptions:

- 500 is represented as [5,0,0]
- minuend is denoted by `mi`
- subtrahend is denoted by `su`

.You can subtract the two arrays of integers using following algorithm:

1. compare `mi.length` with `su.length`
2. if `mi.length` < `su.length` then swap the `array` and after subtraction between the two arrays (doing column wise subtraction moving from last index to `0th` index ) negate the result.
3. if `mi.length` == `su.length` then start comparing element at index i of mi (`mi[i]`) with element at index i of su (`su[i]`). if `mi` turns out to be less than `sr` then swap the `array`. After subtraction between the two arrays negate the result.
4. if `mi.length > su.length` then just perform normal subtraction between two arrays.

Here is the complete code for addition as well as subtraction.

```
//Assumed that none of number represented by array is LPaded by "0s" and the initegers at other than 0th position is not negative.
public class BigNumberAddSubtract
{
    private int array1[];
    private int array2[];
    private boolean shouldBeNegative = false;
    public BigNumberAddSubtract(int[] iArray1, int[] iArray2)
    {
        array1 = iArray1;
        array2 = iArray2;
    }
    public void setArray1(int[] array)
    {
        this.array1 = array;
    }
    public void setArray2(int[] array)
    {
        this.array2 = array;
    }
    //Subtraction 
    private int[] subtract()
    {
        int length1 = array1.length;
        int length2 = array2.length;
        boolean isMinus = false;
        int mi[] = array1 ;//Minuend
        int su[] = array2 ;//Subtrahend
        boolean isPrevEqual = false;
        boolean isFirstNegative = false;
        if (length1 == length2 )                
        {   
            if (array1[0] < 0 )
            {
                isFirstNegative = true;
            }
            for (int i =0 ; i < length1 ; i++)
            {
                if (Math.abs(array1[i]) == Math.abs(array2[i]))    
                {                                                  
                    isPrevEqual = true;
                    continue;
                }
                else if (array1[i] < array2[i])
                {
                    if (isPrevEqual)
                    {
                        isMinus = true;
                        System.out.println("breaking");
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    isPrevEqual = false;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (length1 < length2) 
        {                           
            if (array1[0] < 0)
            {
                isFirstNegative = true;
            }
            isMinus = true; 
        }
        else
        {
            if (array1[0] < 0 )
            {                                                                 
                isFirstNegative = true;
            }
        }
        array1[0] = Math.abs(array1[0]);
        array2[0] = Math.abs(array2[0]);
        if (isMinus)
        {
            mi = array2;
            su = array1;
        }
        int[] result = new int[mi.length];
        int iCursor1 = mi.length - 1;
        int iCursor2 = su.length - 1;
        int iCarry = 0;
        for (int i=result.length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--, iCursor1--, iCursor2--)
        {
            int iValue = 0;
            int iFrom =  0;
            iFrom = mi[iCursor1] - iCarry;                  
            if (iFrom < (iCursor2 < 0 ? 0 : su[iCursor2]))
            {
                if (iCursor1 > 0)
                {
                    iFrom = 10 + iFrom;
                }
                iCarry = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                iCarry = 0;
            }
            iValue = iFrom - (iCursor2 < 0 ? 0 : su[iCursor2]) ;      
            result[i] = iValue;                                       
        }
        int[] temp = null;
        if (isMinus)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            for (int i=0; i < result.length; i++)
            {
                if (result[i] == 0)
                {
                    counter++ ;
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    result[i] = -result[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
            temp = new int[result.length - counter];
            System.arraycopy(result,counter,temp,0,result.length - counter);
            result = new int[temp.length];
            System.arraycopy(temp,0,result,0,temp.length);
        }
        if (isFirstNegative)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            for (int i=0; i < result.length; i++)
            {
                if (result[i] == 0)
                {
                    counter++ ;
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    result[i] = -result[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
            temp = new int[result.length - counter];
            System.arraycopy(result,counter,temp,0,result.length - counter);
            result = new int[temp.length];
            System.arraycopy(temp,0,result,0,temp.length);
        }
        return result;
    }
    //Addition
    private int[] add()
    {
        int length1 = array1.length;
        int length2 = array2.length;
        int[] result = new int[length1 > length2 ? length1 : length2];
        int iCursor1 = array1.length - 1;
        int iCursor2 = array2.length - 1;
        int iCarry = 0;
        array1[0] = Math.abs(array1[0]);
        array2[0] = Math.abs(array2[0]);
        for (int i=result.length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--, iCursor1--, iCursor2--)
        {
            int iValue = 0;
            if (iCursor1 >= 0 && iCursor2 >= 0)
            {
                iValue = array1[iCursor1]  + array2[iCursor2] + iCarry;
            }
            else if (iCursor1 < 0 && iCursor2 >=0)
            {
                iValue = array2[iCursor2] + iCarry;
            }
            else if (iCursor1 >=0 && iCursor2 < 0)
            {
                iValue = array1[iCursor1] + iCarry;
            }
            if (iCursor1 == 0 && iCursor2 ==0)
            {
                result[i] = iValue;
                iCarry = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                result[i] = iValue % 10;            
                iCarry = iValue / 10;               
            }
        }
        result[0] = result[0] + iCarry;
        if (shouldBeNegative)
        {
            result[0] = -result[0];
        }
        return result;
    }
    public int[] performOperation()
    {
        if (array1[0] < 0 && array2[0] < 0)//If digit at one's place of both number is negative
        {
            shouldBeNegative = true;
            return add();
        }
        else if (array1[0] > 0 && array2[0] > 0)
        {
            return add();
        }
        else //if digit at one's place of one of the numbers is negative
        {
            return subtract();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] st)
    {
        int[] arr1 ={-9,0,0,6};
        int[] arr2 = {1,9,7,8};
        BigNumberAddSubtract big = new BigNumberAddSubtract(arr1,arr2);
        int[] addResult = big.performOperation();
        for (int i : addResult )
        {
            System.out.print(i);
        }
    }
}
```

If any test fails or discrepancy found then let me know .

Answer (score -1):

I doubt I fully understand your question, but here is a stab at an answer:

a[i] = 50 - 500;

Edit: That was completely unclear from your question as originally stated. I would stored the digits in the reverse order from what you have stated, so that index 0 is always the "ones" position, index 1 is always the "tens" position, etc. Then you can just loop over the indexes until you have covered them all, treating access past the end of an array as a zero value in that position. You can store the digits in the order you have specified, it just make the loop logic a bit more complex.

Comment: no. OP has an array of ints, each array element is 1 digit of the number. e.g. `x = [5,0]`, `y = [-5, 0, 0]`.

Comment: That was completely unclear from your question as originally stated. I would stored the digits in the reverse order from what you have stated, so that index 0 is always the "ones" position, index 1 is always the "tens" position, etc. Then you can just loop over the indexes until you have covered them all, treating access past the end of an array as a zero value in that position. You can store the digits in the order you have specified, it just make the loop logic a bit more complex.